# Debugging line by line in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I found on microsoft site that if I want to debug a program line by line I need to press F11.
If I press F11 I obtain (in a new form named Program.cs):

```
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Windows.Forms;

     namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
      static class Program
     {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();  
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
    }
    }
```

They add that "When stepping through code, the line that is about to be executed is highlighted". In my case is highlighted:

```
       Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```

Should I choose another line?

Then, they tell to choose Stop Debugging to make the code editor writable.

If I follow this steps, I don't see any modifications. Should I see a new form in which the computer debug line by line? Should I do another thing?

I'm sorry if my question seems stupid. Please understand me that I am a begginer to C#.

Thank you so much!

Comment: See http://www.hermetic.ch/cfunlib/debug.htm Applies to VS also

Comment: Are you sure you understand what does "debugging" stand for? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was trying to achieve an "instruction by instruction". I didn't work with this way of debugging, so I didn't know anything about it. Because of help given by everyone, now I know to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Your question has *less* relation to concrete language (`C#` in the tag) and much more about `Visual Studio` environment.

You press `F11` to execute **not** *line by line*, but *instruction-by-instruciton*, cause if you immagin the code like  this:

`if(condition) { x++; DoSomething(); ...}`, on press of `F11` it **will not** jump all this line but will execute

- first `if`
- after `x++`
- after `DoSomething(..)`

and all this is on the same line in your code, but for *compiler* these are different instructions.

If you want to make editor Editable, it's enough to press `Pause` button. But by clicking `Pause` button, in case if in the scope of the current function there is no any `lambda` expression, you will be able to change the code just in `Pause`, they call this feature [Edit and Continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcew296c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: that's what I want: to execute instruction by instruction. I insert a simple breakpoint, I pressed F11 but I don't see the status of my variable. Where can I see it?

Comment: You can see them in [WatchWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taedcee.aspx), by dragging or writing down variables inside, [Locals Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6td98xe(v=vs.100).aspx),or simply when the program in Pause state, over the mouse over any variable in the current execution scope, and you will see the tooltip-window.

Comment: Thank you very much! I found it!

Comment: @Bogdan: in code provided there is nothing to modify actually. You need to write at least some "Hello world" program. Check out examples on internet, it's impossible to explain everything in one answer.But it's not complicated

Comment: @Bogdan: if your program blocks at some point, and you don't know where: run the program, get to the point when it blocks and click "Pause" in `Visual Studio`, the row/function/iteration where the program blocked will be hitted, cause that is the instruciont that currently running.

Comment: How could I click Pause? Where is it?

Comment: @Bogdan: there is || button like this. I think you need definitely read this: [Debugging Tips with Visual Studio 2010](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/18/debugging-tips-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a few tips on how debugging works:

First of all, you should insert a simple breakpoint (**F9** in Visual Studio) somewhere in the code you want to debug. Let's say you have a Windows Form Application, with a Form called Form1. In this form you have a Button which, when clicked, does something. You would have something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        doSomething(...);
    }
}
```

To stop the execution of the program when you click the button (so you can see exactly what's happening), you can put a breakpoint on the click event. Once you have the breakpoint there, every time the click event is fired, the program will stop, and you will be able to run it step-by-step.

By running it step-by-step, you can see the status of your variables and the data you have stored. So you can locate where your code starts to behave differently from what you expected (what is usually called [a bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug)).

To do so, you can step through the program *procedure by procedure* (**F10**) or *instruction by instruction* (**F11**). F10 will jump over function calls, executing them until they finish. F11 will enter into function calls, executing step by step every instruction in them.

Comment: I followed your steps until I pressed F11. Then, my first instruction from button1_Click became highlighted.Where I can see the status of my variables? Thank you!

Comment: while you are stopped, you can show the data of the scope clicking on Debug>Windows>Automatic. I'm not sure if it's called like this, as I have VS in spanish, not in English

Comment: in case it helps, here's what it looks like in my version: [link](http://i.imgur.com/yKeLG.jpg)

Comment: In English Version Debug->Windows : Output and Immediate. But neither help, unfortunately.

Comment: You can also use the "Inspection" window. There you can write any function call and it will show the result of it (care here, because if the function modifies anything, it will be modified)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! (English version has Windows -> Watch Windows)

Answer (score 0):

You should mark a debug point (or breakpoints), and then start debugging your program. Is not recommended, in my opinion, to start debugging line by line your program, you should debug just the parts that throws exceptions, and for that you mark breakpoints on your program (How to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k80ex6de.aspx). When your program reachs that line, the debugger starts an detail debug line by line if you want.